# Accessing an extern "C" variable in c++ from another file

Tags: c++, scope, global, extern, mingw-w64

I'm using mingw-w64 on Windows 7 Pro 64-bit. In trying to access external variables, after much hair tearing, I finally arrived at this:

```
// MultiTest2.h
// Version 1.0.0
// MDJ 2016/04/13

#ifndef MULTITEST2_H
#define MULTITEST2_H

extern "C" {
    int iXfer;
    int setInt();
}

#endif // MULTITEST2_H
```

does NOT work (I'm using 'extern "C"' instead of just 'extern' because I'm working towards linking to assembly code eventually), but:

```
// MultiTest2.h
// Version 1.0.1
// MDJ 2016/04/13

#ifndef MULTITEST2_H
#define MULTITEST2_H

extern "C" int iXfer;
extern "C" int setInt();

#endif // MULTITEST2_H
```

DOES work!

FYI, the other two files in the system are:

```
// MultiTest2.cpp
// Version 1.0.0
// MDJ 2016/04/13

#include "MultiTest2.h"

int iXfer = 0;

int setInt() {
    iXfer = 6253;
    return 0;
}
```

and:

```
// MultiTest1.cpp
// Version 1.0.0
// MDJ 2016/04/13

#include <iostream>
#include "MultiTest2.h"

using namespace std;

int main() {
    setInt();
    cout << iXfer << endl;
}
```

With Version 1.0.0 of MultiTest2.h (the declarations in an 'extern "C"' block), immediately upon entering:

```
g++ -S MultiTest2.cpp
```

the result is:

```
MultiTest2.cpp:7:5: error: redefinition of 'int iXfer'
 int iXfer = 0;
     ^
In file included from MultiTest2.cpp:5:0:
MultiTest2.h:12:6: note: 'int iXfer' previously declared here
  int iXfer;
      ^
```

But, with Version 1.0.1 of MultiTest2.h (individual 'extern "C"' declarations), the following sequence works perfectly:

```
c:\work\gccWork\MultiTest>g++ -S MultiTest2.cpp
c:\work\gccWork\MultiTest>g++ -S MultiTest1.cpp
c:\work\gccWork\MultiTest>g++ -c MultiTest2.s
c:\work\gccWork\MultiTest>g++ -c MultiTest1.s
c:\work\gccWork\MultiTest>g++ -o MultiTest.exe MultiTest2.o MultiTest1.o
c:\work\gccWork\MultiTest>MultiTest
6253
```

Is this some sort of mingw-w64 idiosyncracy, or is there something I'm missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are not the same.

```
extern "C" int foo;
```

Does TWO things: it declares that foo is extern (i.e. this is a declaration only, and the symbol will be defined by another module), and it declares the linking of foo as "C", which influences the symbol name.

On the other hand,

```
extern "C" {
  int foo;
}
```

only declares that foo has C linking. It does not declare the symbol as extern, which means that this is a definition, not just a declaration.

In other words

```
extern "C" int foo;
```

is the same as (note the repetition of the extern keyword)

```
extern "C" {
  extern int foo;
}
```

Comment: "It does not make the symbol extern..." is not accurate. Non-const objects declared in namespace scope have external linkage by default. There's no need to "make them extern" anyway. What `extern "C"` does not do in this case is it does not turn a *definition* into a *non-defining declaration* (as plain `extern` does).